# Hibernate data fetch type issues

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

**I will explain scenario like this :**

**I have a database where it has some set of tables**

1. Activity
2. Exercise
3. Comprehension
4. Question
5. Sentence

**Best way to describe relations is here,**

1. Activity has set of Exercises.
2. Exercise has set of Questions.
3. Each Exercise has a single Comprehension
4. Each Question has set of Sentences.

This is the way I tried to implement in hibernate :

```
    public Exercise getActivityById(int ActivityId)
    {
         Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
         Activity a = (Activity)session.get(Activity.class, ActivityId);

         session.close();
         return a;
    }

    public List<Exercise> getExercisesFromActivity(Activity a)
    {
         Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

         List<Exercise> e =     a.getExercises();

         session.close();
         return e;
    }

    public Comprehension getComprehensionFromExercise(Exercise e)
    {
         Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

         Comprehension c =     e.getComprehension();

         session.close();
         return c;
    }
 //...... and so on
 // i will call like this
 Activity a = getActivityById(23);
 List<Exercise> e = a.getExercisesFromActivity(a);
 Comprehension c = getComprehension(e.get(0));
 //.... and so on
```

Basically , I am trying to follow the best practice that says , **session per query** . In this approach I got **exception LazyInitializationException** , as the object was already detached.

So, I googled everything and found out, that I can try 4 solutions , I have found same things on multiple websites.

http://uaihebert.com/four-solutions-to-the-lazyinitializationexception/

**Out of these , if i try to make **default-lazy=false** ,or Open Session in View (Transaction in View) both are bad practices .**

**If I use Join query , I think it violates in two ways :**

1. If database is quite huge and we have several tables to join , here in my scenario , according to my understanding I will have to join

   Activity
   Exercise
   Comprehension
   Question
   Sentence
   .........

and more tables ,if I have to do in single join query. 
2. Dosen`t it voilate **session per query** ? , we are asking too much in single session . As a jdbc user , I used to fire single SQL query to fetch each and everything one by one. One connection will help me fetch one table data.
3. If this is correct then all the enterprise apps will need to join n number of tables to work with hibernate and collections which is obviously worst thing to do.

So , Finally , question arises , how can I handle this scenario. What will be the best practice . I asked one person he said something like this

```
public void getEverything()
{
     Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

      Activity a = (Activity)session.get(Activity.class, ActivityId);
      List<Exercises> e = a.getExercises();
      Comprehension c = e.get(0).getComprehension();    
      List<Question> q = e.get(0).getQuestions();

    ApplicationWidePojo apojo = new ApplicationWidePojo();
    // set all the tables , values in this pojo

  session.close

}

// this eliminated lazyinitializationexception
```

but I think this is **not session per query. Or fine grained**

Also , there is one more question. Should I use one single pojo to set whole  data and use application wide? Any other good alternative to this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [session-per-query](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions) is an anti-pattern. You should either:

- use one session per transaction
- extend the session on multiple transactions

If you have a root entity with [multiple children levels](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-multi-level-fetching/), you need to turn the query upside down and fetch from the inner-most child up to the Root entity:

```
select q
from Question q
join fetch q.exercise e
join fetch e.activity a
where a.id = :activityId
```

This query will filter out activities/exercises without a question, but that might be fine in your use case.

Comment: but what if I have huge set of data in all tables, joins will be bad right?

Comment: In this scenario, you don;t want to fetch all that data, especially because you don't display huge amounts of data in the UI. You can use pagination or more filtering criteria.

Comment: Thanks ! Should I use one single pojo to set whole data and use application wide? Any other good alternative to this way?

Comment: A DTO is always better when fetching more data. You could reuse it, but usually it's query bound.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by your previous comment?

Comment: It means you usually have one query response DTO per query method.